Can I switch the type of currently held alternative in std::variant without reinit?
I want to do something like this with std::variant:
union {int a;float b;} scratch_space;
scratch_space.a = 10;
std::cout << scratch_space.b << "\n";

All objects held will have default dtors.
Doing this throws an exception:
std::variant<int, float> v = 1;
std::cout << std::get<1>(v) << "\n";

Context: I want to have a strictly typed arenas when the same memory will be reused on different stages of execution and I want to avoid allocating/initializing too much.
Update
More context:

I want each stage in a pipeline define a struct that lays out the scratch space (incl. layout requirements and such). The structs will be trivially constructable/destructable.
I am struggling with regular union as I want to use variadic template.


"I want to do something like this with std::variant". You mean you want to have UB with std::variant?

You're trying to access a non-active member which is not allowed (Undefined behavior). In other words you cannot use std::variant for type-punning

Imagine initializing a variant<int,std::string> with an int and then trying to access it as std::string. You would be in trouble because the lifetime of the std::string will not have begun (and you have an object in an invalid state, constructor will not have been called). So that is why it is not allowed

Basically the only way you can do type-punning is by having a byte buffer as large as the largest type. Then use std::memcpy to copy to or from the buffer.

std::visit([](auto e){ return std::bit_cast<float>(e); }, v)?

As var as union's go... in C++ forget they exist. It is one big undefined behavior minefield.

@Jarod42 That might do it, because bit_cast will start the lifetime  :)

@PepijnKramer "Imagine initializing a variant<int,std::string> with an int and then trying to access it as std::string. You would be in trouble because the lifetime of the std::string will not have begun (and you have an object in an invalid state, constructor will not have been called). So that is why it is not allowed"
Yeah, I understand that. I will require trivially_destructable and such. Basically, I want different stages in the pipeline define a struct that describes the scratch space. Then they will be able to just access it without extra allocations or memset.

@Jarod42 "std::visit([](auto e){ return std::bit_cast(e); }, v)?" - thanks, will try that.

Added some more context.

You can't read std::cout << scratch_space.b, but you can write to it scratch_space.b = 42. This is all you need for an allocator anyways because the user isn't allowed to rely on the old value still being there.

static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(int)); int i = 1; float f; std::memcpy(&f, &i, sizeof f);  Or what Jarod42 said with std::bit_cast in C++20.

For type-punning use std::bit_cast. The normal input/output type would be std::array<std::byte, sizeof(T)>.
